# Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp

In my UWP app, on click of **AppBarButton** application crashes

Click Event:

```
private void recordBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BtnAcquire.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            BtnIncrement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            BtnPause.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            BtnPrevious.IsEnabled = false;
            BtnNext.IsEnabled = false;
            _startRecording = true;
            _threshold = Convert.ToDouble(TxtThreshold.Text);
            _rootPage.NotifyUser(
                _startAcquisition
                    ? "Record in progress"
                    : "Record is paused",
                _startRecording ? NotifyType.StatusMessage : NotifyType.ErrorMessage);

        }
```

This code is crashing the app in release mode, if I run it in debug mode from Visual Studio it works fine.

If I comment the code in Click event, then app wont crash.

**Error 1 in Event Viewer:**

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a6840de
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.17763.168, time stamp: 0xbb211a61
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x008dcb61
Faulting process id: 0x39f4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4b1b7bb42e78c
Faulting application path: C:\Projects\..\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 18aa82bd-8807-43bc-9ddc-dc7ce186f52e
Faulting package full name: MyApp_1.0.10.0_x86__1cxs26n94vksc
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

**Error 2 in Event Viewer:**

```
Faulting application name: MyApp.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5a6840de
Faulting module name: combase.dll, version: 10.0.17763.253, time stamp: 0xa3f81b2d
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00209931
Faulting process id: 0x18bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4b1b8ec03b132
Faulting application path: C:\Projects\...\bin\x86\Debug\AppX\MyApp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
Report Id: 7ac0d37c-4d5f-4d02-96ec-2bfa2d4f4668
Faulting package full name: MyApp_1.0.10.0_x86__1cxs26n94vksc
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Also when I change configuration manager from `Debug` to `Release` and do build i get the following error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       ILT0005: 'C:\Users\userName\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64.microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\x64\ilc\ilc.exe --gatekeeper @"C:\Projects\Smart\UWP\obj\x64\Release\ilc\intermediate\gkargs.rsp"' returned exit code 1 MyApp
```

Here is a minimal code that can show the error  [**Code Download**](https://fil.email/pQehX0Ld?&showconfirmation=true)

**Reproducing steps**

- Build, Deploy and Run in debug mode
- App will prompt you to **choose a microphone** on PC
- Please select one and click **Next** button
- After you land on next page, click on **Acquire** button
- This will work fine.
- Stop debugging.
- Now go to **Windows Start** and search for **HaBo Recording**
- Launch the app
- Repeat the same steps
- After you click on **Acquire** button, you will notice app will get froze in couple of seconds and then crashed.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's really hard to help you diagnose this issue by the above information.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT here is the project with the minimal code. https://fil.email/9gzEKzfd?&showconfirmation=true If you build, deploy and run in debug mode it will prompt you to choose a microphone on PC, please select one and click on next after you land on next page, click on acquire button. This will work fine. Stop debugging . Now go to windows start and search for HaBo Recording launch the app and repeat the same steps and after you click on acquire button, you will notice app will get froze in couple of seconds and then crashed.

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Issue was with DataGrid Control I am updating it ItemSource in Dispatch.RunAsync, that's crashing the app. So I replaced it with Telerik Grid Control and app is now working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with  `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"`
So I replaced DataGrid Control with Telerik UWP Grid Control as explained over [here](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatagrid/gettingstarted.html) that solved my issue.

Comment: @AvishaiDernis thanks for checking. But still UWP.UI.Controls.DataGrid should also work. I think its bug from Microsoft side

Answer (score 0):

I just messed around with this kind of crash/error on production/deployed app with event error "Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll in UWP application".

As a solution for my case I had to use default "ContentDialog" Style rather then my custom made style!
So if you have used any custom style for any control on that page/window that you want to open, try using without it!

Hope this could solve your problem!

Thank you.